# Eliminar marker a partir de un boton

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

Al darle click al marcador obtengo su ID

```
mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.tema_gris));
    this.miUbicacion();
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marcador_seleccionado=marker.getID(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            if (marker.getTitle() != null) {

...
```

el problema esque quiero eliminarlo despues desde un boton pero no se como podria eliminarlo con saber el Id del marcador, o alguna otra recomendación.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es, a la hora de crear los marcadores, guardarlos en un listado de Markers.

```
//Creamos el arraylist para guardar los marcadores
ArrayList<Marker> listadoMar = new ArrayList<Marker>();

//Creamos el marcador
Marker mar = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(position)
                .title(rV.Get_descripcion())
                .snippet(txt_infoTodas).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

//añadimos el marcador a la lista
listadoMar.add(marker);

...........................
//Cuando vayas a eliminar si tenemos el id del marker a borrar recorremos la lista y eliminamos este marcador
for(int i = 0; i<listadoMar.size; i++)
{
    if(listadoMar.get(i).getId()==id){ //Comparamos los id de los marcadores de la lista con el del marker que queremos eliminar
        listadoMar.remove(listadoMar.get(i));
    }
}

//Ahora que hemos eliminado el marcador, recargamos el mapa
map.clear();  //Primero eliminamos lo que había en el mapa

for(int i = 0; i<listadoMar.size; i++)  //Añadimos todos los marcadores otra vez
{
    map.addMarker(listadoMar.get(i));
}
```

Otra opción que tienes es ocultar el marcador llamando a:

```
Marker.setVisible(false);
```

Llamarías a este método en vez de a remove, ya depende de lo que te vaya mejor.

Respuesta obtenida de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap

Comment: pero yo me refiero por ID, esque no solo sera un marker son muchos.

Comment: obteniendo el id, puecdes buscar el marker en la lista y eliminarlo, es sencillo

Comment: pero eso es lo que no entiendo, como hacerlo.

Comment: He editado la respuesta

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con ésta respuesta. Sólo cambiaría el `ArrayList` por un `HashMap` en el que use ids como keys para mayor eficiencia.

Comment: perfecto, todas las mejoras son bienvenidas =)

Comment: no hay una forma de **no borrar** todos los marcadores del mapa? serán muchos y es molesto para el usuario estar esperando la recarga.